# Disable Selinux not work Centos 7

Tags: centos7, selinux

According manual and several tips on internet

- Edit */etc/sysconfig/selinux* `SELINUX=disabled`
- Edit or search on *grub.conf* for selinux options.
- `touch /.autorelabel`
- Reboot machine

After reboot

```
sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          error (Success)
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

Comment: While I've not played with RHEL/CENTOS 7, usually 'setenforce 0' at the command line avoids having to do a reboot (it will come back after a reboot if you don't disable it elsewhere though)

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed letter 'd' in the end.

In your /etc/selinux/config file change SELINUX=disabled

Do a reboot of the system
    shutdown -r now

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me work add to grub.conf

```
selinux=0

title CentOS (2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=es rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto LANG=es_ES.UTF-8 rd_LVM_LV=vg/lv_swap rd_NO_DM rd_LVM_LV=vg/lv_root selinux=0 rhgb quiet
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64.img
```

After reboot.

Comment: Disabling `selinux` costs you one layer of security. perhaps you might be doing some testing here.. Also such questions would better fit in [\[ U&L \]](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I'm using for 20 years linux without Selinux on more that 100 server. After this years any problem. Security not equal a paranoid. IHMO.

Comment: That sounds wonderful to me, recently we have had  a problem with an unpatched apache just because selinux was turned off for a couple of minutes for testing..

Comment: Just a good timeline for upgrades, use mod_security instead, thre're a lot of ways for secure a server. If your problem it's a proxy exploit, ohh. link to several security mail list for patch your software and your security apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following commands:

```
setenforce 0
sed -i --follow-symlinks 's/SELINUX=enforcing/SELINUX=disabled/g' /etc/sysconfig  
        /selinux
```

Then reboot the machine.
After that check status by using sestatus.

Answer (score 0):

for me it was working to update the grub2 bootloader:
disable the selinux there fixed it for me.

```
sed -i 's/consoleblank=0 crach/consoleblank=0 selinux=0 crash/g' /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```